# unable to start a new project eclipse

Tags: java, android

I am a new android developer.

I was trying to install eclipse in my system and after installation when I was to open a new project the column of build target is been empty.

So i can't create or start a project... please help me in rectifying this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install platforms/sdks with the SDK Manager. Go to Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager->Available Packages

There you should select what you want.

Comment: ya thank you but it shows that "Location of android has not been setup in preferences". So i get into windows->preferences->Android, in sdk target i cant identify where the "tools" folder

Comment: The tools folder is where you unpacked/installed your SDK. Point it to the location where you have installed the Android SDK

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup an Android virtual device (AVD), go to the SDK manager, select an API version and download it, after that go to the AVD tab and create a new virtual device.

You also have to indicate the android SDK path in Eclipse settings, then the AVD you've created is gonna show up in the "target" field.